# Inline Edit and Save not working with apex:selectlist

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, inlineeditsupport

I have a set of select options in a dropdown which the user selects and based on the option selected different sets of pageblocktables are rendered. I want them to be able to inline edit and save each of these tables. When I give these tables inline edit/save functionality without using the select list, it works perfectly. However, when I use inline editing with selectlist; after click on the save button, the page reloads but then does not show any tables and data does not get saved. I am guessing there is problem with the doSave() function in my code.

VF code:

```
<apex:page controller="OppsController">
<apex:form >
   <apex:panelGrid columns="2">
        <apex:selectList value="{!SectionNames}" required="True" size="1" multiselect="false">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!SectionItems}" />
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!updateData}"/>   
        </apex:selectList> 

   </apex:panelGrid> 


 <apex:outputPanel >
 <apex:outputPanel id="section1" rendered="{!section1}" >
  <apex:pageBlock >
<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!doSaveUS}" />
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!OppContentUS}"  var="item" style="text-align:left;" >
             <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="SaveActiveState"  /> 

                    <apex:facet name="header">US New Business This Quarter</apex:facet>

                    <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Owner.Name</apex:facet>
                           {!item['Owner.Name']}
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Account Name</apex:facet>
                            {!item['Account.Name']}
                    </apex:column> 
                     <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Opportunity Name</apex:facet>
                            {!item['Name']}
                    </apex:column>                     
                    <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Stage</apex:facet>
                           {!item['StageName']}          
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Total Contract Value</apex:facet>
                            {!item['Total_Contract_Value__c']}  
                    </apex:column>  
                    <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Tier</apex:facet>
                             {!item['Opp_Tier_Group__c']}  
                    </apex:column> 
                    <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Notes</apex:facet>
                             {!item['Opp_Owner_Notes__c']}  
                    </apex:column>                      
</apex:pageBlockTable>


</apex:pageBlock>  
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>   


 <apex:outputPanel >
 <apex:outputPanel id="section2" rendered="{!section2}" >
 <apex:pageBlock >
  <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!doSaveUK}" />
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!OppContentUK}"  var="item" style="text-align:left;" >
             <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="SaveActiveState"  /> 

                    <apex:facet name="header">UK New Business This Quarter</apex:facet>

                    <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Owner.Name</apex:facet>
                           {!item['Owner.Name']}
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Account Name</apex:facet>
                            {!item['Account.Name']}
                    </apex:column> 
                     <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Opportunity Name</apex:facet>
                            {!item['Name']}
                    </apex:column>                     
                    <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Stage Name</apex:facet>

                               <apex:outputfield value="{!item.StageName}" ></apex:outputField>     
                    </apex:column>   
                    <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Total Contract Value</apex:facet>
                            {!item['Total_Contract_Value__c']}  
                    </apex:column>  
                    <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Tier</apex:facet>
                             {!item['Opp_Tier_Group__c']}  
                    </apex:column> 
                    <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Notes</apex:facet>
                             {!item['Opp_Owner_Notes__c']}  
                    </apex:column>                      
</apex:pageBlockTable>                 
</apex:pageBlock>  
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Controller:

```
public with Sharing class OppsController {

      public String SectionNames {get;set;}
      public Boolean section1 {get; set;}
      public Boolean section2 {get; set;}


      public List<SelectOption> getSectionItems(){
        section1 = false;
        section2 = false;

         List<SelectOption> SectionNames = new List<SelectOption>();
         SectionNames.add(new SelectOption('','-- Select --'));
         SectionNames.add(new SelectOption('USA New Business','USA New Business'));
         SectionNames.add(new SelectOption('UK New Business','UK New Business'));
         return SectionNames;

     }


       public Pagereference updateData() {
         if(SectionNames == 'USA New Business') {
              section1 = true;                     
         } 

         else if(SectionNames == 'UK New Business') {

              section2 = true;  
         }

        return null;
     }

List<Opportunity> oppsUK = new List<Opportunity>(); 
List<Opportunity> oppsUS = new List<Opportunity>(); 

public OppsController()  {
     oppsUK =  [SELECT ID, Account.ID, Account.Name, Name, Owner.Name, CloseDate, StageName, Opp_Tier_Group__c, Opp_Owner_Notes__c, Total_Contract_Value__c    
               FROM Opportunity
               WHERE CloseDate = THIS_QUARTER and  Sales_Team__c = 'EMEA' AND Type = 'New Business' 
                ]; 

oppsUS =  [SELECT ID, Account.ID, Account.Name, Name, Owner.Name, CloseDate, StageName, Opp_Tier_Group__c, Opp_Owner_Notes__c, Total_Contract_Value__c    
               FROM Opportunity
               WHERE CloseDate = THIS_QUARTER and  Sales_Team__c = 'US' AND Type = 'New Business' 
                ]; 
      }   

   public List<Opportunity> getOppContentUK() {                                      
        return this.oppsUK;
    }




    public PageReference doSaveUK() {
        system.debug(oppsUK);
        update oppsUK;
        return ApexPages.CurrentPage();

    }



   public List<Opportunity> getOppContentUS() {                                      
        return this.oppsUS;
    }




    public PageReference doSaveUS() {
        system.debug(oppsUS);
        update oppsUS;
        return ApexPages.CurrentPage();

    }
}
```

Comment: How do you format this damn thing??!! Its cutting off half the code

Comment: Edit our post, select the Visualforce or Apex and click the {} button to format.

Comment: @KeithC Any idea about the posted question?

Comment: You're probably getting a `DmlException`. Wrap your `update` call in a `try`/`catch`. In your `catch` block make sure you call `ApexPages.addMessages` then `return null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue with

```
 public List<SelectOption> getSectionItems(){
        section1 = false;
        section2 = false;

         List<SelectOption> SectionNames = new List<SelectOption>();
         SectionNames.add(new SelectOption('','-- Select --'));
         SectionNames.add(new SelectOption('USA New Business','USA New Business'));
         SectionNames.add(new SelectOption('UK New Business','UK New Business'));
         return SectionNames;

     }
```

Remove

```
section1 = false;
section2 = false;
```

this and add into constructor

what happend constructor always call once when page load
but this `getSectionItems` method
call everytime whenever we call a method from page

Comment: I added this in. Same issue. Not saving. Page reloads and the tables disappear.

Comment: are you able to get picklist values i controller?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. The table values after edit are not getting saved. The selectlist seems to be blocking the update.

Comment: @Mike I just used your code in my org it is working fine

Comment: I am indeed using it. I have used apex:inlineEditSupport in my table and I use apex:outfield on the ones I want to inline edit. It works perfectly without apex:selectList but with that inlineEditing doesn't work.

Comment: @Mike Just a quick question I got your issue. Just tell me one thing when you click on save(after changing stagename picklist ) what should happend It get update only?

Comment: It should update that opportunities stage. However, right now when I click save it only reloads and the edits are not saved. Also, after reload the table does not appear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33205/discussion-between-ratan-and-mike).